# Extract data from wharehouse stock, group by article but, if description change, use the last USED

Tags: sql, excel, adodb

I've one file xls and in the 1th sheet I've the records of my goods stock, I extract this file each year and i put the result into the last row in the same table.
I try to match the last 3 year, the Article code are UNIQUE but the description has been changed.
There are one way to group by article code, and if the description has changed use the last found?
this is the file

[image]

this is my query, I use ADODB.Connection:

```
SELECT tab1[Codice Articolo], tab1Descrizione, Sum(IIf([anno]=2017,[qta],0)) AS Qta2017, Sum(IIf([anno]=2017,[Tot],0)) AS Val2017, Sum(IIf([anno]=2017,[€Pz],0)) AS Cad2017, Sum(IIf([anno]=2018,[Qta],0)) AS Qta2018, Sum(IIf([anno]=2018,[Tot],0)) AS Val2018, Sum(IIf([anno]=2018,[€pz],0)) AS Cad2018, Sum(IIf([anno]=2019,[Qta],0)) AS Qta2019, Sum(IIf([anno]=2019,[Tot],0)) AS Val2019, Sum(IIf([anno]=2019,[€pz],0)) AS Cad2019
FROM tab1
GROUP BY tab1.[Codice Articolo], tab1.Descrizione;
```

this is the qry result

[image]

and this is that I hope to be possible to have:
[image]

I think that I need to use one join with the same table, I try some variant of this code, without right:

```
SELECT t1[Codice Articolo], t2.Descrizione,(IIf(t1.[anno]=2017,t1.[qta],0)) AS Qta2017, Sum(IIf(t1.[anno]=2017,t1.[Tot],0)) AS Val2017, Sum(IIf(t1.[anno]=2017,t1.[€Pz],0)) AS Cad2017, Sum(IIf(t1.[anno]=2018,t1.[Qta],0)) AS Qta2018, Sum(IIf(t1.[anno]=2018,t1.[Tot],0)) AS Val2018, Sum(IIf(t1.[anno]=2018,t1.[€pz],0)) AS Cad2018, Sum(IIf(t1.[anno]=2019,t1.[Qta],0)) AS Qta2019, Sum(IIf(t1.[anno]=2019,t1.[Tot],0)) AS Val2019, Sum(IIf(t1.[anno]=2019,t1.[€pz],0)) AS Cad2019
FROM tab1 t1
LEFT JOIN (Select t2.Descrizione from Tab1 t2 on t2.anno = max(t1.anno)
LEFT JOIN 
GROUP BY tab1[Codice Articolo], t2.Descrizione;
```

Are the correct way but the errore is on the code ore are wrong the approach?
thank for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the description, whose value is sometimes equal to the article code, and sometimes not. This creates new groups, which is not what you want.

Here is one way to avoid that:

```
SELECT 
    tab1[Codice Articolo], 
    Max(IIf(tab1[Codice Articolo] <> tab1Descrizione, tab1Descrizione, null)) AS tab1Descrizione
    Sum(IIf([anno]=2017,[qta],0)) AS Qta2017, 
    Sum(IIf([anno]=2017,[Tot],0)) AS Val2017, 
    ..., 
    Sum(IIf([anno]=2019,[€pz],0)) AS Cad2019
FROM tab1
GROUP BY tab1.[Codice Articolo], tab1.Descrizione;
```

Comment: for this tread I extract just fiews article; 
bat I've mutch case where on 2017 the code are the same at description, but in the 2018 or 2019 the description change.
If the description are the same at the codeproduct or not, is equal, the goal is use alvays the descrisption onthe last year.
in any case, yr code get me this error:
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'
I use excel,  ADODB with Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Answer (score 0):

I was sure that the solution to my problem was with JOIN QUERY, I can't see the light because I needed two JOIN.

this is the solution I found:

```
strsql = "SELECT t1.[Codice Articolo], t2.Descrizione," & _
"Sum(IIf(t1.[Esercizio]=2017,t1.[NrPz],0)) AS Qta2017," & _
"Sum(IIf(t1.[Esercizio]=2017,t1.[€Tot],0)) AS Val2017," & _
"Sum(IIf(t1.[Esercizio]=2017,t1.[€Pz],0)) AS Cad2017," & _
"Sum(IIf(t1.[Esercizio]=2018,t1.[NrPz],0)) AS Qta2018," & _
"Sum(IIf(t1.[Esercizio]=2018,t1.[€Tot],0)) AS Val2018," & _
"Sum(IIf(t1.[Esercizio]=2018,t1.[€pz],0)) AS Cad2018," & _
"Sum(IIf(t1.[Esercizio]=2019,t1.[NrPz],0)) AS Qta2019," & _
"Sum(IIf(t1.[Esercizio]=2019,t1.[€Tot],0)) AS Val2019," & _
"Sum(IIf(t1.[Esercizio] = 2019, t1.[€pz], 0)) As Cad2019 " & _
"FROM ([temp$] t1 INNER JOIN [temp$] AS t2 ON t1.[Codice Articolo] = t2.[Codice Articolo]) INNER JOIN (SELECT Max([Esercizio]) AS maxdiEsercizio, [Codice Articolo] FROM [temp$] GROUP BY [Codice Articolo]) t3 ON (t2.[Codice Articolo] = t3.[Codice Articolo]) AND (t2.Esercizio = t3.maxdiEsercizio) " & _
"GROUP BY t1.[Codice Articolo], t2.Descrizione;"
```

Thanks.
fabrizio